# bit-wise operation unary ~ (invert)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I'm a little confused by the `~` operator. Code goes below:

```
a = 1
~a  #-2
b = 15
~b  #-16
```

How does `~` do work?

I thought, `~a` would be something like:

```
0001 = a
1110 = ~a
```

why not?

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027394/what-does-the-mean-in-python.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You are exactly right. It's an artifact of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer representation.

In 16 bits, 1 is represented as `0000 0000 0000 0001`. Inverted, you get `1111 1111 1111 1110`, which is -2. Similarly, 15 is `0000 0000 0000 1111`. Inverted, you get `1111 1111 1111 0000`, which is -16.

In general, `~n = -n - 1`

Comment: how do I get that bit representation string in python 3?

Comment: In python interactive shell, try it as print(int('0001', 2))

reference:https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation

Comment: That's the inverse function of what Janus wants I believe.

Comment: The inverse of `int('00101010', 2)` would be `f'{42:08b}'`, for example. The formatting `08b` results in the binary representation of 42 padded with zeros if the number of characters is less than 8.

Comment: @Janus: easiest way to the bit String: bin( mynumber ), same with hex. numbers: hex( mynumber )

Comment: @karsten `bin` emits actual minus signs, it doesn't use two's complement. `bin(-1) == '-0b1'`. This answer is about two's complement.

Comment: @Janus: True.  
I used it like bin(0xff) = '0b11111111'. Is there a way to force Python to see a number as unsigned?Probably one has to mask with & 0xff

Answer (score 38):

The '~' operator is defined as:
"The bit-wise inversion of x is defined as -(x+1). It only applies to integral numbers."[Python Doc - 5.5](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations)

The important part of this sentence is that this is related to 'integral numbers' (also called integers). Your example represents a 4 bit number.

```
'0001' = 1
```

The integer range of a 4 bit number is '-8..0..7'. On the other hand you could use 'unsigned integers', that do not include negative number and the range for your 4 bit number would be '0..15'.

Since Python operates on integers the behavior you described is expected. Integers are represented using two's complement.  In case of a 4 bit number this looks like the following.

```
 7 = '0111'
 0 = '0000'
-1 = '1111'
-8 = '1000'
```

Python uses 32bit for integer representation in case you have a 32-bit OS. You can check the largest integer with:

```
sys.maxint # (2^31)-1 for my system
```

In case you would like an unsigned integer returned for you 4 bit number you have to mask.

```
'0001' = a   # unsigned '1' / integer '1'
'1110' = ~a  # unsigned '14' / integer -2

(~a & 0xF) # returns 14
```

If you want to get an unsigned 8 bit number range (0..255) instead just use:

```
(~a & 0xFF) # returns 254
```

Comment: integers have unlimited precision in both python 2 and 3

Comment: @AnttiHaapala By the time you commented, you didn't expect so many upvotes. I think it's worth mentioning the details as "Does your statement change anything regarding the bit manipulation?" or maybe it's worth editing the answer.

Comment: @user1767754 good point, which is why I've closed this question as a duplicate of another Q/A that gives the correct answer.

Comment: Note that with the simplification of the `int` type in Python 3, `sys.maxint` became obsolete.  It doesn't even exist anymore in my Python 3.8.

Answer (score 28):

It looks like I found simpler solution that does what is desired:

```
uint8: x ^ 0xFF
uint16: x ^ 0xFFFF
uint32: x ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
uint64: x ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also use unsigned ints (for example from the numpy package) to achieve the expected behaviour.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bin( ~ np.uint8(1))
'0b11111110'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the number represented by the result of applying ~ is not well defined as it depends on the number of bits used to represent the original value. For instance:

```
5 = 101
~5 = 010 = 2

5 = 0101
~5 = 1010 = 10

5 = 00101
~5 = 11010 = 26
```

However, the two's complement of ~5 is the same in all cases:

```
two_complement(~101) = 2^3 - 2 = 6
two_complement(~0101) = 2^4 - 10 = 6
two_complement(~00101) = 2^5 - 26 = 6
```

And given that the two's complement is used to represent negative values, it makes sense to consider ~5 as the negative value, -6, of its complement.

So, more formally, to arrive at this result we have:

1. flipped zeros and ones (that's equivalent to taking the ones' complement)
2. taken two's complement
3. applied negative sign

and if x is a n-digit number:

```
~x = - two_complement(one_complement(x)) = - two_complement(2^n - 1 - x) = - (2^n - (2^n - 1 - x)) = - (x + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation for anyone wanting a *literal inversion of bit digits* in an integer's semantic binary representation.

e.g., **`0b110010` -> `0b1101`** and not `0b110010` -> `-0b110011` as with `~` operator.

```py
def bit_invert(n: int) -> int:
    """Calculate the bitwise inverse of n.

    Doesn't do funky stuff with sign bits, like Python's built-in bitwise not.
    """
    return n ^ ((1 << n.bit_length()) - 1)
```

## Example

```py
>>> for i in range(16):
...     print(i, bin(i), bin(bit_invert(i)))
... 
0 0b0 0b0
1 0b1 0b0
2 0b10 0b1
3 0b11 0b0
4 0b100 0b11
5 0b101 0b10
6 0b110 0b1
7 0b111 0b0
8 0b1000 0b111
9 0b1001 0b110
10 0b1010 0b101
11 0b1011 0b100
12 0b1100 0b11
13 0b1101 0b10
14 0b1110 0b1
15 0b1111 0b0
```