# basic bit flip algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am new to programming. I took a basic course in Python, so I know the basic. I am trying to practice a lot more. I am attempting this question and I don't know where to start.

> You will be given a list of 32-bits unsigned integers. You are
> required to output the list of the unsigned integers you get by
> flipping bits in its binary representation (i.e. unset bits must be
> set, and set bits must be unset).
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line of the input contains the list size T. T lines follow
> each line having an integer from the list.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 100
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Output one line per element from the list with the requested result.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> 3  2147483647  1  0
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> 2147483648  4294967294  4294967295
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Take 1 for example, as unsigned 32-bits is
> 00000000000000000000000000000001 and doing the flipping we get
> 11111111111111111111111111111110 which in turn is 4294967294

Comment: Just like you attempted your baby freeze you should also give it a try for this question too.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278779

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can be done with the bitwise XOR operator, which is `^` in Python.

Example:

```
a = 0xF0101010
b = 0xFFFFFFFF
print(bin(a))
print(bin(b))
print(bin(a ^ b))

0b11110000000100000001000000010000
0b11111111111111111111111111111111
0b1111111011111110111111101111
```

Answer (score 10):

```
foreach x in input:
    x_flipped = ~x & 0xffffffff
    print "bits flipped in unsigned 32-bit", bin(x_flipped)
```

Explained: 
- (~x) flips all bits
~ (& 0xffffffff) converts 2's complement into unsigned int.

Comment: is this the way that you were suggesting?

def flipflop(bits):
    the_bit = raw_input("")
    bit_flipped = ~(the_bit) &  0xffffffff
print bin(bit_flipped)

I am getting a traceback error that says that bit_flipped is not defined