# ~1 and ~0 giving strange results in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

&, |, ^, and ~ are all bitwise operators in python. &, ^, and | are all working fine for me - when i take, say, 1|0, I get 1. But ~ is giving me strange results. ~1 gives me -2, and ~0 gives me -1. Is this because I'm using integers or something? I'm running python 3.

I'm hoping to get 1 from ~0, and 0 from ~1 (the integers). Is this possible?

Comment: What do you expect ~1 and ~0 to give you ?

Comment: @nos `-2` and `-1` respectively. Interestingly `~True` and `~False` give the same results

Comment: Lookss right to me. What are you expecting?

Comment: it is all in the documentation https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: possible duplicate of [bit-wise operation unary ~ (invert)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278779/bit-wise-operation-unary-invert)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

**`~x`**

> Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1. This is the same as -x - 1.

Following the last part of that statement:

`-1 - 1` does indeed equal `-2`

and

`-0 - 1` does indeed equal `-1`

Answer (score 3):

That's because of [the two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) implementation of integers.

If you switch all bits from `0000 0000` (assuming 8 bit integers here, but it's still valid for larger ones), you get `1111 1111`. In two's complement interpretation, that's -1, because to represent -1, you take 1, invert all bits and add one:

```
   0000 0001 (= 1)
-> 1111 1110 (inverted)
-> 1111 1111 (added one, now this is '-1')
```

The same works for your second example.