# Understanding the ~ bitwise operator

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

The documentation says:

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its plain or long integer argument.

I'm understanding this as: "the invert operator should invert each bit."  So 8 in binary is 1000, so to me ~8 should be 0111 or 7, but instead ~8 is -9.  So how in the world is the inversion of 1000 -9?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Do a little digging into the topic of the *two's complement* representation of integers.

Comment: @Tripleee The duplicate doesn't contain anything about `~` used in this context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278779/bit-wise-operation-unary-invert might be more relevant.